# Adding 2 double numbers in c# (visual studio)

Tags: c#

So, When I run the program and enter 2 numbers (e.g. 2.4 and 4.5), the result of adding is 69 and it isn't 6.9.
But, when I run program and type 2,4 and 4,5 the result is 6,9?

Can anyone help me with this one. I am running this in Visual Studio 2019.
The code is down below!

Code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
        double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter a another number: ");
        double num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()); 
       
        Console.WriteLine(num1+num2);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like culture settings.

Comment: Did you know some countries write "one thousand two hundred thirty four point five six" as "1.234,56" ? Seems to me like your machine thinks it's in one of those places .. (the parsing routing is being kind enough to ignore your erroneously placed thousands separator `.` in `2.4` and interpreting your input as twenty four)

Comment: Use [`Double.Parse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.parse?view=net-5.0#System_Double_Parse_System_String_System_Globalization_NumberStyles_System_IFormatProvider_) with the appropriate number styles and format provider fitting your culture input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your O/S region settings for numbers. In Windows 10: Control Panel > Region > Additional Settings. Look specifically at the Decimal symbol and Digit grouping symbol. Your code worked for me. When I changed the region settings on my machine (decimal symbol to a comma and Digit grouping symbol to a period), it worked as you described.